# Mirroring System Drive On Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid

I have server 2008 installed on a hard drive that disc management calls a "basic volume." On this hard drive I have partitions configured for certain sets of data.

I want to buy a second hard drive and mirror the entire system drive over (including all partitions.) Is this possible or is it impossible to mirror the system drive?

Also, I know I need to convert both discs to dynamic volumes before this could possibly happen. Will I lose any data converting my basic disc to dynamic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is most certainly possible to convert and mirror the disk containing OS and boot partition to a dynamic disk without data loss.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/354e5163-f388-4354-984c-ea4e4206694c#sectionSection1) This behavior is unchanged in Windows Server 2008.

In Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`), right-click the disk and select **Convert to Dynamic Disk**.
You will have to reboot after converting the basic disk to dynamic. Now all partitions have been converted to simple volumes, and these can be mirrored to another Dynamic Disk.

Simply right-click each volume, select **"Add mirror..."** and choose the other Dynamic Disk (your second hard drive of equal size). Wait for the volumes to sync and voila, you've mirrored your System Volume